# Calendar control GUI C++ library

Tags: c++, user-interface

Who knows a good component for a "calendar control" (NOT date/time picker)?
"Calendar control" means something like Mozilla Sunbird: [image: Mozilla Sunbird]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.org](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/images/sunbird-week-view.png))</sub>

Requirements to the control:
- C++;
- Day/Week/Month view;
- Support of several calendars;
- Without MFC dependences;

Nice to have:
- Open source;
- Cross plathform;
- Free;
- Minimum external dependences (boost etc are fine);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unlikely to find such a control ready made.
Even more unlikely to find one for C++ without MFC dependencies.

Your best bet is to implement it yourself.

Comment: I think it will take a lot of time to implement it myself.

Answer (score 1):

The [Qt Framework](http://qt.nokia.com/products) has [an example calendar](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.2/richtext-calendar.html) that you can use as a starting point, although it is nowhere near as complete as what you are looking for. No sensible GUI framework will have such a widget out-of-the-box.